# LINQ: IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: linq

I have an LINQ entity like so:

```
ID1 INT
ID2 INT
ID3 INT
Value VARCHAR(50)
```

ID1, ID2 & ID3 are composite primary keys. It has no association with any other entity.

An **IndexOutOfRangeException** is thrown whenever I update or delete after **SubmitChanges**.  I'm running on .NET 3.5 SP1.

I have tried creating another project, still on .NET 3.5 SP1, but don't encounter that exception.

Here is the code:

```
        DataClasses context = new DataClasses();
        Entity entity = (from entities in context.Entities
                              where entities.ID1 == 3
                                && entities.ID2 == 1
                                && entities.ID3 == 1
                              select entities).First();

        context.Entities.DeleteOnSubmit(entity);
        context.SubmitChanges();
```

Here is the exception:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Index was outside the bounds of the array."
  Source="System.Data.Linq"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.MultiKeyManager`3.TryCreateKeyFromValues(Object[] values, MultiKey`2& k)
       at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.IdentityCache`2.Find(Object[] keyValues)
       at System.Data.Linq.IdentityManager.StandardIdentityManager.Find(MetaType type, Object[] keyValues)
       at System.Data.Linq.CommonDataServices.GetCachedObject(MetaType type, Object[] keyValues)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.GetOtherItem(MetaAssociation assoc, Object instance)
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.BuildEdgeMaps()
       at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
       at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
       at Project.Page.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\ProjectFolder\Project\Page.aspx.cs:line 31
       at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Is there a record meeting your criteria?

Comment: Yes. It returns a single record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-created the DBML from scratch. Sigh...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that LINQ To SQL (has/had) trouble with composite keys. The actual source is `MultiKeyManager` and `TryCreateKeyFromValues(Object[] values`

This [ElegantCode post on SubmitChanges throws IndexOutOfRangeException](http://elegantcode.com/2008/08/25/submitchanges-throws-indexoutofrangeexception/) has the exact same error as yours, with similar conditions. The difference is that he's got another field to modify the .dbml model and mark as PK.

Are you able to modify/remove in your .dbml model the `PrimaryKey=true` attributes for the 3 ints?

The key quote from that article:

> Remove the PrimaryKey=true attributes from SomeType and SomeValue, and add that on the ViewID property, and now LinqToSql handles the association correctly.

Comment: I did what you told me to and it still throws out the same error. Thanks.